How can I delete a holiday from a person in vue.js?
I am new to vue.js and I make a project with vue.js and django I write this code in vue.js
<i class="mdi mdi-trash-can"
 @click.prevent="confirm(holiday.id)"
 ></i>
  deleteHoliday(holidayID){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    session.delete(`api/person/${this.$route.params.id}/holiday/${holidayID}/actions/`).then(()=>{
      this.fetchPersonHolidays();
    });
    this.drawerMsg =
      "";
  },5000);
},
confirm(holidayID){
  Swal.fire({
    title: "",
    text: "",
    icon: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#34c38f",
    cancelButtonColor: "#f46a6a",
    confirmButtonText: ""
  }).then((result)=>{
    if (result.value){
      eventCreate(`${holidayID}`, 3)
      this.deleteHoliday(holidayID)

      Swal.fire(
        "",
        "success"
      );
    }
  });

And in django I write this in url file
path('api/person/<int:pk>/holiday/<int:id>/actions/', PersonHolidaysActionsView.as_view())

And in views.py file this:
class PersonHolidaysActionsView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdminUser]
serializer_class = PersonHolidaysSerializer
queryset = PersonHoliday.objects.all()

But I can't delete the holiday of the person.

Needs debugging details.  We can't run your code, so you must provide this information.  There's many steps between clicking the delete button and the holiday being deleted on the backend.  You need to figure out both where and what the actual problem is.  You should be able to narrow it down by adding logs to your code.  Then you need to provide what error and/or unexpected values are being seen.
